# How can i make my Colored object detection and tracking program more efficient?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

First of all, thanks to all the stackoverflow users for their help. I really appreciate it. 
So, I have made a colored object detection program. I am able to control the mouse clicks and even paint some stuffs in MS paint. 
Now, i have to present my work in my engineering design contest in my college. I need to make my program more effective. Firstly, the object that I have used to track and move is a red colored object and I filtered out the surrounding colors by adjusting the HSV values. 
But, I have seen some problems when I tried my code in different surroundings. There are many red colored objects in the surrounding and my program was detecting those objects and giving me false values. 

**So, my goal is:-** I have to make my program work in almost all surroundings and make the program independent of the background. My program should only track and detect the object I want. Since, I am a freshman undergraduate and my knowledge is limited. So, I want some advice from the stackoverflow experts. Thanks. Please I don't want source code as I want to understand and rectify my mistakes.

Comment: Hey, how do the red objects in the background look, similar to your tracking object? Maybe, can you provide an example image? Is the camera fixed or moving while tracking?

Comment: @Dennis:- Dennis, the red object that i used is basically a coke bottle cap. So, when i tried the program by changing the surrounding conditions and placed various red objects such as a red cap, a red line on my tshirt,a red pen etc.When i checked my threshold image, i found those objects showed up in the threshold image and my program showed "Too much noise in the background,cant detect any object". I think i have to upload a picture or so such that u can get my situation better.Is there any way i can make my program detect objects of only specific area such objects which r like coke cap?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have got a binary image as output of your color filtering, then:

1. Use `findContours()`-function (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) to extract your objects. You get the contours of all red objects inclusive your coke cap.
2. Now you have to distinguish between your coke cap and the rest of the red colored objects. In your case it would be appropriate to use morphologic features like the area (as you mentioned) and the circularity of the objects (caps are circular!):

   - Area can be calculated by `contourArea()`-function (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) and compared with a threshold.
   - The circularity of an object can be calculated by `circularity = (4*PI*A)/P^2`, where *A* is the area (calculated by the above function) and *P* is the perimeter of the object. The perimeter is the output of `arcLength()`-function (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#arclength). A circle has got a circularity of 1. You can compare the values of your objects with it.

To sum up, use the features *object's area* and *object's circularity* to differ coke caps from other red objects.

Comment: :- thanks dennis. I sincerely appreciate your help. Your ideas really helped me a lot. I have calculated the circularity of my object and it comes around 0.8-0.9. Reason being for some reason, its not completely circular. Also, as i move it around my window, at some points it sort of breaks down(kind of like fragments) and the circularity reduces to 0.7 but still i sort of filtered out some bigger objects using the circularity option.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce noise (number of false detections) you can try to use double thresholding (I maybe wrong, but I think it is called hysteresis thresholding, approach used in Canny edge detector):

1. You need to create 2 images, one thresholded with t1=50, another with t2=150 (you can adjust parameters to get more stable performance, i.e. heuristically find the optimal values).
2. For each non black pixel (x,y) in t2: floodFill t1 with gray at (x,y), floodFill t2 with black at (x,y)
3. once done erase all non-gray pixels in t1.

Now t1 should have a good likelihood estimate for possible positions of the colored ball.

Note: Thresholding doesn't neccessaraly means that you have to use opencv "threshold" function. You can write your own that takes as an input a color and a range within which the colors will be passed.

If you are looking for only one ball, simply use findContours function to find contour with the biggest area.

Don't try to achieve 100% performance, remember: "Perfect is the enemy of good" - Arisotle.